# creating a new numpy array from a datframe based on quadrants

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, conditional-statements

I would like to loop trough a pandas dataframe colunm or a numpy array to add the new column or numpy array to the original dataframe using conditional formatting to assisting the quadrants of course angles. The column COG consists of courses of ships of which i want to know the quadrants of the angles

Something like this:

```
['cog']  ---   ['quad_cog']
53.250000  --- 1
111.450001 --- 2
231.675003 --- 3
336.000000 --- 4
```

Conditional formats:

```
  0 > cog >  90 --- 1 
 90 > cog > 180 --- 2
180 > cog > 270 --- 3
270 > cog > 360 --- 4
```

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://github.com/LukeCaptainAI/norm_quad/blob/main/aisdecoded.csv?raw=true' # forked from github
df = pd.read_csv(url, index_col=0)
df.head()

# Numpy array of interst:
cog = np.array(df['cog'])
```

How can I loop trough a dataframe df['cog'] or numpy array numbering the angles based on their respective quadrants?

Answer (score 0):

Use np.select()

```
np.select([(df.cog>0)&(df.cog<90),
          (df.cog>90)&(df.cog<180),
           (df.cog>180)&(df.cog<270),
          (df.cog>270)&(df.cog<360)],
         [1,2,3,4])
```